# How does ASP.Net MVC resolve controllers?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to build an asp.net mvc 4 application.

I want the application to encompass both a HTML site and a restful api, e.g.

www.mysite.com/MyDetails/
www.mysiste.com/api/users/{userid}/Details/

In the above example I would use 2 controller classes.

1. MyDetailsController which inherits from System.Web.Mvc.Controller
2. DetailsController which inherits from System.Web.Http.ApiController

I've also added a simple 'Users Route' to the WebApiConfig:

routeTemplate: "api/users/{userid}/{controller}/{id}

In my early testing it appears as though the following scenarios are invalid:

www.mysite.com/api/users/12345/MyDetails/
www.mysite.com/Details/

Both of those return a 404.

This is definitely a good thing but what I'm trying to find out is why doesn't it work?
Can I rely on it not working or is it just coincidence in my simple test?

I've read about people struggling to develop a single MVC app/project that encompasses both HTML and REST apis but the most common complaint seems to be you can't duplicate controller names and it still seems like you can't simply use a namespace to differentiate them.

In this example I've deliberately designed the class names to avoid any conflict so what other gotchas are waiting to trip me up?

Thanks,

Chris A

Answer (score 1):

Check your routes file, should be `Global.asax` under `RegisterRoutes`. The `MapRoute` call should tell you everything you need to know for MVC routing. Keep in mind, the order of the routes is important: top routes take priority over the bottom. Web API uses the `WebApiConfig` class and `MapHttpRoute` call to configure routes.

Comment: I guess the bit I don't understand is how come MapRoute doesn't resolve a System.Web.Http.ApiController and MapHttpRoute doesn't resolve a System.Web.Mvc.Controller? I guess it just doesn't but I'm trying to find out if that's deterministic behavior or not?

Comment: It is the way the framework is built. It is called the request pipeline and MVC has a separate pipeline from Web API.

Comment: Ah, so the bit I didn't realise is there's separate request pipelines for an MVC site and the Web API - seems weird seeing as they're both in the same project/application. Thanks

Comment: You could add aspx pages to the same project - would you then expect aspx+mvc+api to all use the same pipeline?   It's strange because they're both modern(ish) web technologies developer at (roughly) the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Please ensure you have put a (MVC) route on top of the action you wish to hit of your controller, default action being index.

```
    [System.Web.Mvc.Route("Help")]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.DocumentationProvider = Configuration.Services.GetDocumentationProvider();
        return View(Configuration.Services.GetApiExplorer().ApiDescriptions);
    }
```

Code above will hit this action method (provided your controller is registered and derived either from apiController or Controller) in the following way:
http://localhost:54541/help inside your IISExpress.

To register please do the following:

In "global.asax.cs", you’ll need to add:

AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();